# Getting CSS menu layout just right?

Tags: html, css

I've been playing with CSS menus of three levels for a little bit, but I can't seem to get the layout quite right.  The menu, on the HTML side, is just a bunch of nested unordered lists:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two
    <ul id="sub">
      <li>Three
        <ul id="subsub">
          <li>Three One</li>
          <li>Three Two</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Four</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with the CSS in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckLAd/

What I'd like to have is the `menu` "One Two" be a horizontal menu bar (that's working) with the `sub` menu "Three" and "Four" lining up exactly below "Two".  At the moment they are a little off to the right.  Then, hovering over "Three", the `subsub` menu "Three One" and "Three Two" should appear horizontally aligned with the item "Three" but aligned to the right.

It's the alignments that puzzle me.  The submenu is currently aligned using `left: 3em; top: 0;` but that seems rather hacky to me.  Are there ways to do this better and more precise?

Also, how can I improve on the CSS, clean it up and make it more compact?

On a similar note, another menu I play with is transparent when I load the page (ie the content is visible through the `li` elements), but the moment I scroll the page just a pixel the `li` solidify.  When they are transparent, they also disappear when the `li:hover` isn't satisfied for the parent `ul`.  Haven't quite figured out what's happening there yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you must set `position: relative` on the parent li of the #sub. That way you can position #sub relatively to it.

See the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ckLAd/1/

Improve css:

- Never do ul#id, but just #id. It is enough.
- Never use id, but classes instead. Ids are too specific.

Comment: Thanks for the hints.  I tinkered a little more with it, removed the pixel width, and cleaned up the CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/ckLAd/2/